# Permission denied on files in a directory on a CIFS-mounted Windows share in Linux

Tags: permissions, cifs, access-control, shared-folders

I can successfully mount a windows share over the network from my Raspberry/Jessie with both, mount.cifs and fstab entrye then mount -a.

E.g. `sudo mount.cifs //HPSERVER/linux-bup/ /home/maxg/bmsOnSrvr -v -o user=linux,pass=****`

However, when I want to write to that Windows share I get Permission denied.
I can read the files on the share.

This is what I can see on the linux machine:

```
# [2018-04-17 21:13] maxg@rpi32 ~/bmsOnSrvr $
la
total 5
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Apr 17 21:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 maxg maxg 4096 Apr 17 19:15 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    4 Apr 17 21:04 deleteme.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 Apr  8 11:50 desktop.ini
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Apr 17 19:15 rPi32
```

Th windows share allows the user 'linux' full access, as can be seen by using CACLS:

```
C:\>cacls d:\shares\linux-bup
d:\shares\linux-bup BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)F
                CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)F
                Everyone:(OI)(CI)F
                HPSERVER\linux:(OI)(CI)F
                NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)F

C:\>cacls d:\shares\linux-bup\rPi32
d:\shares\linux-bup\rPi32 BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)F
                      CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)F
                      Everyone:(OI)(CI)F
                      HPSERVER\linux:(OI)(CI)F
                      NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)F

D:\shares\linux-bup>echo . >deleteme.txt

D:\shares\linux-bup>cacls d:\shares\linux-bup\deleteme.txt
d:\shares\linux-bup\deleteme.txt BUILTIN\Administrators:F
                             Everyone:F
                             HPSERVER\linux:F
                             NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:F
```

I am out of ideas, as to why I have no access.
What else do I need to get access?

Answer (score 6):

Further digging revealed a `noperm` parameter that can be used on the mount command:

```
sudo mount.cifs //HPSERVER/linux-bup/ /home/maxg/bmsOnSrvr --v -o user=linux,pass=****,noperm
```

result now:

```
# [2018-04-17 21:45] maxg@rpi32 ~/bmsOnSrvr $
la
total 5
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Apr 17 21:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 maxg maxg 4096 Apr 17 19:15 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    4 Apr 17 21:04 deleteme.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 Apr  8 11:50 desktop.ini
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Apr 17 19:15 rPi32
# [2018-04-17 21:45] maxg@rpi32 ~/bmsOnSrvr $
echo kjskjs>max.txt
# [2018-04-17 21:45] maxg@rpi32 ~/bmsOnSrvr $
rm desktop.ini
# [2018-04-17 21:45] maxg@rpi32 ~/bmsOnSrvr $
la
total 5
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Apr 17  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 maxg maxg 4096 Apr 17 19:15 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    4 Apr 17 21:04 deleteme.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    7 Apr 17 21:45 max.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Apr 17 19:15 rPi32
```

[edit] However, it looks like this is the proper way of doing it:

```
sudo mount.cifs //HPSERVER/linux-bup/ /home/maxg/bmsOnSrvr --v -o user=linux,pass=****,uid=1001,gid=1001
```

result now:

```
# [2018-04-17 21:59] maxg@rpi32 ~/bmsOnSrvr $
la
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 maxg maxg    0 Apr 17 21:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 maxg maxg 4096 Apr 17 19:15 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 maxg maxg    0 Apr 17 19:15 rPi32
# [2018-04-17 21:59] maxg@rpi32 ~/bmsOnSrvr $
echo crap>crap.txt
# [2018-04-17 21:59] maxg@rpi32 ~/bmsOnSrvr $
la
total 5
drwxr-xr-x 2 maxg maxg    0 Apr 17 22:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 maxg maxg 4096 Apr 17 19:15 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 maxg maxg    5 Apr 17 21:59 crap.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 maxg maxg    0 Apr 17 19:15 rPi32
```

Comment: uid and gid likely need to come from `id -u <username>` and `id -g <username>`. Or at least that's what I did based on this answer, and it worked :) .

Answer (score 0):

After mounting root become the drive owner. Thus in time of mounting we have to use `uid` and `gid` parameter for assigning particular user and group.

The following command should do your job.

```
sudo mount.cifs //HPSERVER/linux-bup/ /home/maxg/bmsOnSrvr --v -o user=linux,pass=****,uid=1001,gid=1001
```